# How can a variable be part of another variables name in lua?

Tags: variables, lua

I want to set dynamic variable names.

such as

```
function make(name)
local name..bar = "ipsum"
end

make(foo)
```

this possible?

Comment: Can you give an example of why you would want to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For globals it's simply indexing like `_G[name..bar]`. For locals you could emulate this by setting all globals you use in a local table, and index that one. For an approach to really use a local, I can't help you.